# How to dynamically update plotly chart with new data from yahoo finance?

Tags: python, charts, plotly, visualization, finance

I wanted to build a chart where I download financial data from yahoo finance and then trim it to the last 100 columns and plot it dynamically every minute as new data comes in. Here is my code so far

```
`import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.subplots as sp
import time

# Download the initial data from Yahoo Finance
data = yf.download('EURUSD=X', period='7d', interval='1m')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df.iloc[-100:]

# Create a Plotly line chart
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=df1.index, y=df1['Close'], mode='lines')])


# Create a Plotly subplots object with the line chart
subplots = sp.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)
subplots.add_trace(fig.data[0], row=1, col=1)

# Set the chart title and axis labels
#subplots.update_layout(title='Prices', xaxis_title='Date', yaxis_title='Price')
subplots.update_layout(title='Prices',
              xaxis_title='Date',
              yaxis_title='Price',
              plot_bgcolor='#0a192f',
              paper_bgcolor='#0a192f',
              font=dict(color='white'),
              xaxis=dict(showgrid=False),
              yaxis=dict(showgrid=False))

# Show the chart
subplots.show()

# Update the chart with new data in real-time
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    data = yf.download('EURUSD=X', period='7d', interval='1m')
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df3 = df2.iloc[-100:]

# Update the x and y data of the line chart trace
fig.data[0].x = df3.index
fig.data[0].y = df3['Close']

# Update the Plotly subplots object
subplots = sp.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1)
subplots.add_trace(fig.data[0], row=1, col=1)
subplots.update_layout(title='Prices', xaxis_title='Date', yaxis_title='Price')

# Show the updated chart
subplots.show()`
```

In my code above, what I get is multiple charts for every loop iteration but what I am trying to get is updating the same chart with new data everytime instead of making new charts